# Dwarf DW_AT_location objdump and dwarfdump inconsistent

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering

I am playing around with CPython and trying to understand how a debugger works.
Specifically, I am trying to get the location of the last `PyFrameObject` so that I can traverse that and get the Python backtrace.

In the file `ceval.c`, line 689 has the definition of the function:

`PyObject * PyEval_EvalFrameEx(PyFrameObject *f, int throwflag)`

What I am interested in getting is the location of `f` on the stack. When dumping the binary with `dwarfdump` I get that `f` is at `$rbp-824`, but if I dump the binary with `objdump` I get that the location is `$rbp-808` - a discrepancy of 16. Also, when debugging with GDB, I get that the correct answer is `$rbp-808` like `objdump` gives me. Why the discrepancy, and why is `dwarfdump` incorrect? What am I not understanding?

How to technically recreate the problem:
Download `python-2.7.17.tgz` from Python website. Extract.

I compiled python-2.7.17 from source with debug symbols (`./configure --enable-pydebug && make`). Run the following commands on the resulting `python` binary:

`dwarfdump Python-2.7.17/python` has the following output:

```
                        DW_AT_name                  f           
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /home/meir/code/python/Python-2.7.17/Python/ceval.c
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x000002b1                         
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x00002916>
                        DW_AT_location              len 0x0003: 91c879: DW_OP_fbreg -824
```

I know this is the correct `f` because the line the variable is declared on is `689 (0x2b1)`. As you can see the location is:

`DW_AT_location              len 0x0003: 91c879: DW_OP_fbreg -824`: Meaning `$rbp-824`.

Running the command `objdump -S Python-2.7.17/python` has the following output:

```
PyEval_EvalFrameEx(PyFrameObject *f, int throwflag)
{
   f7577:       55                      push   %rbp
   f7578:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   f757b:       41 57                   push   %r15
   f757d:       41 56                   push   %r14
   f757f:       41 55                   push   %r13
   f7581:       41 54                   push   %r12
   f7583:       53                      push   %rbx
   f7584:       48 81 ec 38 03 00 00    sub    $0x338,%rsp
   f758b:       48 89 bd d8 fc ff ff    mov    %rdi,-0x328(%rbp)
   f7592:       89 b5 d4 fc ff ff       mov    %esi,-0x32c(%rbp)
   f7598:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   f759f:       00 00 
   f75a1:       48 89 45 c8             mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
   f75a5:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
```

Debugging this output will show you that the relevant line is:
`f758b:       48 89 bd d8 fc ff ff    mov    %rdi,-0x328(%rbp)` where you can clearly see that `f` is being loaded from `-0x328(%rbp)` which is `$rbp-808`. Also, GDB supports this finding.

So again, the question is, what am I missing and why the 16 byte discrepency between `dwarfdump` and reality?

Thanks

Edit:
The `dwarfdump` including the function above is:

```
< 1><0x00004519>    DW_TAG_subprogram
                      DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                      DW_AT_name                  PyEval_EvalFrameEx
                      DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /home/meir/code/python/Python-2.7.17/Python/ceval.c
                      DW_AT_decl_line             0x000002b1
                      DW_AT_prototyped            yes(1)
                      DW_AT_type                  <0x00000817>
                      DW_AT_low_pc                0x000f7577
                      DW_AT_high_pc               <offset-from-lowpc>53969
                      DW_AT_frame_base            len 0x0001: 9c: DW_OP_call_frame_cfa
                      DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites yes(1)
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x00005bbe>
< 2><0x0000453b>      DW_TAG_formal_parameter
                        DW_AT_name                  f
                        DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /home/meir/code/python/Python-2.7.17/Python/ceval.c
                        DW_AT_decl_line             0x000002b1
                        DW_AT_type                  <0x00002916>
                        DW_AT_location              len 0x0003: 91c879: DW_OP_fbreg -824
```

According to the answer below, `DW_OP_fbreg` is offset from the frame base - in my case `DW_OP_call_frame_cfa`. I am having trouble identifying the frame base. My registers are as following:

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0xfffffffffffffdfe       -514
rbx            0x7f6a4887d040   140094460121152
rcx            0x7f6a48e83ff7   140094466441207
rdx            0x0      0
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x0      0
rbp            0x7ffd24bcef00   0x7ffd24bcef00
rsp            0x7ffd24bceba0   0x7ffd24bceba0
r8             0x7ffd24bcea50   140725219813968
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x0      0
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x7f6a48870df0   140094460071408
r13            0x7f6a48874b58   140094460087128
r14            0x1      1
r15            0x7f6a48873794   140094460082068
rip            0x5559834e99c0   0x5559834e99c0 <PyEval_EvalFrameEx+46153>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

As stated above, I already know that `%rbp-808` works. What is the correct way to do it with the registers that I have?

Edit:
I finally understood the answer. I needed to unwind one more function, and find the place my function was called. There, the variable I was looking for really was in `$rsp` and `$rsp-824` was correct

Comment: I'm not familiar with CPython at all, but when it comes to stack traces there are great tools like [FRIDA](https://frida.re/) or [GEF](https://github.com/hugsy/gef).

Comment: CPython is really just the example. My issue is the discrepency and I am trying to understand the DWARF and why this issue exists. There are many tools that do what I want, but I want to understand the implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `DW_OP_fbreg -824`: Meaning `$rbp-824`

It does *not* mean that. It means, offset `-824` from *frame base* (virtual) register, which is not necessarily (nor usually) equal to `$rbp`.

You need to look for `DW_AT_frame_base` to know what the frame base in the current function is.

Most likely it's defined as `DW_OP_call_frame_cfa`, which is the value of `$RSP` *just before* current function was called, and is equal to `$RBP-16` (8 bytes for return address saved by the `CALL` instruction, and 8 bytes for previous `$RBP` saved by the first instruction of your function).

Comment: Thanks! I edited my above answer, the frame base is `DW_OP_call_frame_cfa` as you say, but `$rsp` does not help me. Can you tell me why (I posted my registers)?